# How to derive class from CFindReplaceDialog? (MFC)

Tags: windows, mfc

Is it possible to derive custom-built dialog from CFindEditDialog? I want to build a dialog template in Viasual Studio Resource Builder (to draw it), then to hide the default Find dialog window and to use my instead.

MSDN says:

> To customize the dialog box, derive a
>   class from CFindReplaceDialog, provide
>   a custom dialog template, and add a
>   message map to process the
>   notification messages from the
>   extended controls. Any unprocessed
>   messages should be passed to the base
>   class.
>
> Customizing the hook function is not
>   required

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: I can't help you with that, but maybe you should consider moving to .Net, as MFC is a bit outdated. IMO .Net has a much better API than MFC.

Comment: sorry had to vote the answer down. Not only did it not answer the question it proposed a different programming lang.

Comment: .Net still uses C++. It's not a different language. It's a different framework.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have direct experience with this (but close others), it is quite possible and should be easish. Most of the messages will be implemented virtually, so you mearly need to override the ones you're interested in with code you add.

Code project has an artical that talks about CFindEdit.  It might be helpfull
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Media_PlayerByyazan_nemer.aspx
If you take a look at the oninitialize event for an of your dialogs, you should see how events are worked into inherited classes.